# hide databases in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have Localhost as Open connection and Localhost as server administrator.
I have several databases inside my localhost. some thing like this:

```
Localhost -> db_1
          -> db_2
```

Now I want to make a new open connection named test1. (which I can do it without any problem but after creating test1 I have all the databases which exists in localhost). BUT I JUST WANT TO SEE THE db_2 in test1 Open connection. some thing Like this:

```
test1 -> db_2
```

any help plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to create a new server instance and then configure you database with new security :)